# Is it easier to extract CO2 from seawater than from air?

Tags: hydrocarbons, extraction

It takes some effort to extract $\ce{CO2}$ from air in order to produce synthetic and potentially 'green' fuel. Doesn't seawater provide this environmental $\ce{CO2}$ more easily?

Comment: It is not the extraction of CO2 that poses any difficulty (after all, there are many sources of it, such as fossil-fuel fired electric generators and cement production). It is the process of changing CO2 into fuel that requires energy. The question is *non sequitur*.

Comment: @DrMoishe Yeah... except the title says "*Is it easier to extract $CO_2$ from seawater than from air?*", and the body of the post essentially asks the *same* thing. The OP does mention the *potential* use of $CO_2$ as a green fuel, but I only see it as a helpful pointer/example (Before reading the body, I was curious to know what the OP had in mind), **not** the central idea of the post. So yeah, title and body corroborate (perhaps not obvious at first glance?). ;-)

Comment: As for closing the question, I'm unsure as to whether opt for "Primarily opinion-based" or "Too broad"... because the question is somewhere in the middle. A good question, but it might help if the OP restricted answers to *specific* sets of methods.

Comment: How would you propose to concentrate CO2 from sea water in a way that is more efficient than air distillation?

Comment: @airhuff I would not. I am asking wether or not such a method exists.

Comment: @paracetamol What opinion may it be that makes me ask this?